# Assigning value to an array element inside a function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

A simple function

```
auto f = [] (const array <GLfloat, 4> a, array <GLfloat, 4> b) {b [2] = a [2] + 5;};
```

does not work as expected - array *b* remains unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing by *value* and simply modifying the copied array, which has nothing to do with the outer `b`. You have to pass by reference:

```
auto f = [](const array<GLfloat, 4>& a, array<GLfloat, 4>& b) {b[2] = a[2] + 5;};
                                                       ^^^^
```

You should pass `a` by reference-to-const as well, to avoid the unnecessary copy.